# node socketIO upgrade 0.9.17 to 1.34 breaks application

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My app no longer works after upgrading socketIO from 0.9.17 to 1.3.4.

Can anyone help? this is my app

Normally when I launch I should see

```
info   -socket.io started
```

Now I see nothing, no errors either.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server,{transports:['flashsocket', 'websocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']});

var port = Number(8080);
server.listen(port);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

var temp;
 var _this = this;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('connection '+socket)
        socket.on("data",function(d){console.log('data from flash: ',d);});
        socket.emit("message","wtfwtwftwftwf hello from server");
        socket.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
            console.log("disconnect");
        });

        console.log('_this ='+_this);
        _this.socket=socket;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [current socket.io documentation](http://socket.io/docs/) suggests this which is slightly different than what you have:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {transports:['flashsocket', 'websocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']});

var port = Number(8080);
server.listen(port);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

var temp;
var _this = this;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('connection '+socket);
    socket.on("data",function(d){console.log('data from flash: ',d);});
    socket.emit("message","wtfwtwftwftwf hello from server");
    socket.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
        console.log("disconnect");
    });

    console.log('_this ='+_this);
    _this.socket=socket;
});
```

Also, your assignment of `_this.socket=socket;` looks troublesome because this appears like it would only ever work for one client connected at a time.  As soon as you have more than one webSocket connection, the second connection would overwrite the first.

Also, you should make absolutely sure you're using compatible socket.io libraries on client and server (e.g. same version on both ends).

Comment: close but no cigar. did you test it? I see no socketIO started message when I run

Comment: @eco_bach - I don't see any code that would produce such a message.

Comment: @eco_bach - why do you think you'd get that message?  The test should be whether your client and server can send messages to one another.  Also, please see my comments about your use of `_this`.  That seems wrong to be assigning your socket the way you are.

Comment: thanks, The  socketIO started message I assume is legacy from 0.9x socketIO implementation.  Still having problems adding transports configuration to latest socketIO...it seems the wiki needs updating:)